# Google drawings - can not open .wmf file now

Tags: google-drawings

Does Google drawings support .wmf file now? I remember ever do that before, but today, when I upload a .wmf file to GDrive, then try to open it with Google Drawings, it do not list .wmf file then I can not load it to Google Drawings!

If not, which vector image format Google Drawings support today?

Comment: This is not related to programming. You should ask this on SuperUser or some other SE site instead